# GCC C++ override -frtti for single class

Tags: c++, gcc, rtti

Is there a way to avoid generating of typeinfo for whole translation unit or some class when it is compiled with `-frtti` ?

Maybe there is a magic `#pragma` or `__attribute__` that can override command line option?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems for me, that there is no possible magic. Moreover, it seems for me that any kind of such magic would be disruptive.

The only magical GCC pragma that allow user to fine-tune compilation options from inside code is `pragma GCC optimize`.

This pragma works function-wise, because optimizer itself works function-wise and you can easily see, that **it has no effect on RTTI generation for types**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

struct X
{
  virtual int foo() {return 0;}
};

#pragma GCC optimize ("no-rtti")

struct Y
{
  virtual int foo() {return 0;}
};

#pragma GCC reset_options

int
main ()
{
  std::cout << "X: " << sizeof (X) << " " << typeid(X).name() << std::endl;
  // next line should *NOT* build/link if the pragma was taken into account
  std::cout << "Y: " << sizeof (Y) << " " << typeid(Y).name() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

In GCC 5.2, output is:

```
X: 8 1X
Y: 8 1Y
```

Comment: My expectation would be that leaving out RTTI would not affect the size of the object -- type information is stored as a vtable entry for classes that have one, and is generated from the static type for anything that doesn't have a vtable. So compiling without RTTI does not give much of a benefit, except for embedded software where every byte counts.